# Error: "reloc_library cannot locate 'fdatasync'"

Tags: adb, 2.1-eclair, system-error

I have my phone connected to my laptop via the USB cable and ADB is able to identify the device. When I run `adb devices` it returns the phone in the list of connected devices. Running the command `adb shell` now gives an error stating:

> reloc_library cannot locate 'fdatasync'

Running any command on the terminal emulator installed on my phone also returns the same error.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: What device do you have?  Are you rooted or running a custom ROM?

Comment: I can't find anything about this error. It might be your ROM... or you may need to factory restore?

Comment: I am using a Garmin-Asus nuvifone A10. I do not have a custom ROM on the device but yes, it is rooted.

Comment: I have already tried doing a complete factory reset but that did not help either.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716227/why-do-i-get-a-cannot-locate-error-from-reloc-library) looks related somewhat to your issue. it looks like it might be an issue with your ROM, even though it is stock.